# OrderBy a string converted to a double with culture problems using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to convert and order a set of strings.

The Model:

```
public class PartnerSearchResultDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Distance { get; set; }
    public int Classification { get; set; }
}
```

Where I have for example a set:

```
IList<PartnerSearchResultDTO> partnersDTO = new List<PartnerSearchResultDTO>();
partnersDTO = 

Id = 1 | Distance = "2,7" | Classification = 1
Id = 2 | Distance = "5"   | Classification = 1
Id = 3 | Distance = "4,3" | Classification = 1
Id = 4 | Distance = "5,2" | Classification = 1
Id = 5 | Distance = "8"   | Classification = 1
```

And I order like this:

```
partnersDTO = partnersDTO.ToList().OrderBy(p =>  double.Parse(p.Distance)).ToList();
```

If the Browser's language is set to Portugues "pt-PT", it order correctly:

```
2,7 -> 4,3 -> 5 -> 5,2 -> 8
```

If the Browser's language is set to English "en-us", it ignores the comma and orders like this:

```
5 -> 8 -> 2,7 -> 4,3 -> 5,2
```

Comment: Yeah so change `double.Parse()` to something that can handle commas regardless of the current culture. See duplicate.

Comment: For your example the easiest solution would be to replace *double.Parse(p.Distance)* with *double.Parse(p.Distance, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-PT"))* that will always treat comma as a decimal separator.

Comment: Hi @kaarel great! It solved the problem, can you please post your answer so I can set it has correct?

Comment: @Patrick As the question has been marked as duplicate, no answers can be added at this time. Glad it worked.

Comment: Ok @kaarel but the duplicated question don't present a solution for this specific case, but thank you for your help :)